# Sent data from servlet to jsp and dynamically generate dropdown list

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

In a servlet I have a list which has data.  I put that list in a method `doget()` to access it in the onPage Load event.

```
List<Integer> list = pse.populateemployee();
request.setAttribute("list", list);
```

I want to send that list to my JSP page using JSTL.

I tried this:

```
<select name="selectemployee">
 <c:forEach var="employees" items="${list}">
     <option> <c:out value="${employees}"/> </option>
 </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I am using MVC

Why isn't this working?

Comment: _donot no why it is not working_ What's not working? Specifically.

Comment: data from list is not shown in select optin

Comment: in <option> tag try to write: 
<option> ${employees} </option> instead

Comment: Show us how you are dispatching to the `jsp` as well.

Comment: RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("adduser.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

Comment: @Elior +1. There's no need to use `<c:out>` in this case

Comment: @haroonHussain Have you included the appropriate JSTL JAR files? Just in case see this local SO JSTL page: [JSTL info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem

i'm running jsp page insted of servlet thats why jsp page is not get data from servlet on load

now tell me how to mapp my servlet in XML file to runn servlet first instead of jsp

Comment: This is covered by every basic servlet tutorial. Do some research.

Comment: Check out the following popular tutorials: [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html). And also these lessons, they have nice big pictures to illustrate concepts: [Server-side Programming](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/index.html#WebApp).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the link .. for example you are in `jsp` page, and if you want to go from `jsp` to `servlet`, you need to give the path .. ( `./servlet name` in jsp page)

```
<form action="./servlet name" method=post>
<\form>
```

You also should close the `form`.